# HTML 5 video tag video and audio de-synchronisation

Tags: html, audio, video

While having a video play through my local website, it's audio and video become de-synced after a while, like 40 minutes or so, also if I pause the video and then un pause it... I don't know if this is a problem with html 5, my browser, computer or what? But my audio is around 1 second ahead of the video, it's very noticeable... here's my code for the video in case it matters:

```
    echo    "<video class=\"videoContainer\" controls autoplay>
        <source src=\"$movieUrl\" type=\"video/mp4\">
    </video>";
```

I couldn't find any solution for this, in-fact... I couldn't find anyone with this same problem!

P.S Refreshing the page fixes the issue but I don't want to do that every time the video de-syncs... Also I don't have de-sync issues on YouTube etc...

Comment: this has nothing to do with your code. it's an issue with your computer. you can try clearing your cache, stopping other programs that are running in the background, etc.

Comment: Which cache may I ask? :/ Can I have some instructions where/how to clear it please. As with the background programs, notepad++ and chrome, I watch movies on my local site while I code websites.

Comment: those questions aren't suited for a programming site. however, there's tons of stuff on google about this exact issue. good luck.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=online+video+becomes+out+of+sync&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no good API for synchronizing things with the timeline of a video, for instance captions or infoboxes. The spec has had "cue ranges" for this purpose earlier (which even earlier were "cue points"); it is expected that something similar will be added in the future, including support for declarative captions.

However, for now, you will have to either use a timer and read currentTime, or listen for timeupdate and read currentTime. timeupdate is fired at 15 to 250 ms intervals while the video is playing, unless the previous event handler for timeupdate is still running, in which case the browser should skip firing another event. Opera currently always fires it at 250 ms intervals while the video is playing, while Firefox currently fires it once per rendered frame. The idea is to allow the event to be fired at greater intervals if the system load increases, which could save battery life on a handheld device or keep things responsive in a heavy application. The bottom line is that you should not rely on the interval being the same over time or between browsers or devices.

Let's say you want to show a div element between the times 3s and 7s of the video; you could do it like this:

```
Hello world!  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; var hello = document.getElementById('hello'); var hellostart = hello.getAttribute('data-starttime'); var helloend = hello.getAttribute('data-endtime'); video.ontimeupdate = function(e) { var hasHidden = hello.hasAttribute('hidden'); if (video.currentTime > hellostart && video.currentTime
```

The hidden attribute indicates that the element is not relevant and should be hidden. This is not supported in browsers yet, so you have to hide it with CSS:

```
*[hidden] { display:none }
```

The data-starttime and data-endtime attributes are custom data-* attributes that HTML5 allows to be placed on any element. It's great for including data that you want to read with script, instead of abusing the class or title atributes. HTML5 also has a convenience API for data-* attributes, but it's not supported in browsers yet, so we have to use getAttribute a little longer.

The above would look like this using a timer instead:

```
Hello world!  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; var hello = document.getElementById('hello'); var hellostart = hello.getAttribute('data-starttime'); var helloend = hello.getAttribute('data-endtime'); setInterval(function() { var hasHidden = hello.hasAttribute('hidden'); if (video.currentTime > hellostart && video.currentTime
```

This will run every 100 ms. Whether you should use setInterval or timeupdate depends on what you're doing and whether you're ok with the interval changing. Note that the setInterval example above also runs when the video is not playing, which the timeupdate example doesn't. It's possible to clear the interval with clearInterval when the video stops playing and setting it again when it starts playing, though.

If you want to synchronize something with the time playback starts, or after a seek, you should listen for playing and seeked — not play or seeking. The former indicate when playback has actually started and a seek has finished, respectively, while the latter indicate that playback or seeking has just been requested, but could take some time before it actually occurs.

Comment: The browser will actually try to make a match between the video's fps and the refresh-rate of the screen. So using a `requestAnimationFrame()` loop should more precise than any `setTimeout`, `setInterval` which are just ways to stack a function call, but should never be used with something about timing, seriously...